# Does the flow of a vector field contain all and only its integral curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I have seen the flow of a vector field as the only local $\mathbb{R}$-action on a smooth manifold such that a handful of properties are verified (for example that $\forall p \in M$  $\theta_p:I\to M$ is a maximal integral curve or that $\frac{df(\theta (t=0,p))}{dt} = X_p (f)$).
My question is: from visual intuition the flow basically describes the evolution of each point on the manifold subjected to the vector field, so intuitively I'd say that it's nothing less and nothing more than just the set of every integral curve. Is this correct or am I missing something

Comment: The flow is not a set, so it can't be "the set of every integral curve".

Comment: True , it was an abuse of notation. The flow isn't a set but if we fix p it gives us the integral curve passing through that point, so doesn't it basically encode the set of every integral curve?

Comment: Are you asking if every point $q\in M$ lies on some integral curve passing through $p$?

Comment: It sounds to me that you're missing something, Trebor's good point aside: The set of all integral curves is a partition of a manifold into curves (which are sets of points) while the flow is a mapping that determines a parametrization of each integral curve. <> If that's what you're asking, _no, they are not the same_. A complete set of integrals curves does not uniquely determine the vector field or the flow.